# Poor performance using $lte and $gte MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am currently working with MongoDB 3.6.1, and I am facing an strange behavior using **compound index**. I have a collection with around 2 millions of documents, and here is the structure of one document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5af478b408e0f42946ff14ec"),
"IpStart" : NumberLong(50331649),
"IpEnd" : NumberLong(54525951),
"Latitude" : "47.634",
"Longitude" : "-122.342",
"PostalCode" : "98109",
"MarketId" : 308,
"City" : "Seattle",
"State" : "WA"
}
```

And my indexes look like:

```
[
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "locations_fact.IpRangeLocations"
        },
        {
            "v" : 2,
            "unique" : true,
            "key" : {
                "IpStart" : 1,
                "IpEnd" : 1
            },
            "name" : "IpStart_1_IpEnd_1",
            "ns" : "locations_fact.IpRangeLocations"
        }
]
```

When I made this query:

```
db.IpRangeLocations.find({"IpStart":{$lt:1209192009}, "IpEnd":{$gt:1209192009}}).explain("executionStats")
```

I got a response of 5 secs, when it is checking only 955043 keys.

Here is the response with the explain option enable:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "locations_fact.IpRangeLocations",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "IpStart" : {
                        "$lt" : 1209192009.0
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "IpEnd" : {
                        "$gt" : 1209192009.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "IpStart" : 1,
                    "IpEnd" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "IpStart_1_IpEnd_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "IpStart" : [],
                    "IpEnd" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "IpStart" : [ 
                        "[-inf.0, 1209192009.0)"
                    ],
                    "IpEnd" : [ 
                        "(1209192009.0, inf.0]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 5019,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 955043,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4823,
            "works" : 955043,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 955041,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 7530,
            "restoreState" : 7530,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 1,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4773,
                "works" : 955043,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 955041,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 7530,
                "restoreState" : 7530,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "IpStart" : 1,
                    "IpEnd" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "IpStart_1_IpEnd_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "IpStart" : [],
                    "IpEnd" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "IpStart" : [ 
                        "[-inf.0, 1209192009.0)"
                    ],
                    "IpEnd" : [ 
                        "(1209192009.0, inf.0]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 955043,
                "seeks" : 955042,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "SOLANOD",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.1",
        "gitVersion" : "025d4f4fe61efd1fb6f0005be20cb45a004093d1"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Then when I removed the compound index, I got better results (1.932 sec), but it is checking 1726879 documents (more that using Index)

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "locations_fact.IpRangeLocations",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "IpStart" : {
                        "$lt" : 1209192009.0
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "IpEnd" : {
                        "$gt" : 1209192009.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "IpStart" : {
                            "$lt" : 1209192009.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "IpEnd" : {
                            "$gt" : 1209192009.0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1916,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1726879,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "IpStart" : {
                            "$lt" : 1209192009.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "IpEnd" : {
                            "$gt" : 1209192009.0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1697,
            "works" : 1726881,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 1726879,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 13531,
            "restoreState" : 13531,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 1726879
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "SOLANOD",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.1",
        "gitVersion" : "025d4f4fe61efd1fb6f0005be20cb45a004093d1"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Also I tried creating separate index (one for IpStart and another one for IpEnd) with no improvement.

When I made the same query on SQL using between statement and with a compound index there:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ip_range_location] WHERE ipaddress BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end
```

it takes no more than 300ms.

I was expecting that Mongo will answer under 100ms, but I am not sure what will be wrong here.

Any idea is great, thanks

Comment: It is not "between", it is open range - everything started before and ended after 1209192009. It doesn't explain why IXSCAN is significantly slower than COLLSCAN though.

Comment: Could you try using an descending index on IpEnd.  db.<>.createIndex({IpStart:1,IpEnd:-1})

Comment: I confirm COLLSCAN is ~3 times quicker on 3.6.4 with following mgeneratejs: `{"IpStart" : {"$integer": {"min": 0, "max": 2000000000}}, "IpEnd" : {"$integer": {"min": 0, "max": 2000000000}}, "Latitude" : {"$latitude": {"fixed": 3}}, "Longitude" : {"$longitude": {"fixed": 3}}, "PostalCode" : "$zip", "MarketId" : {"$integer": {"min":100, "max": 999}}, "City" : "$city", "State" : "$state"}`

Comment: Creating descending index doesn't help, I got responses between 4 and 3 secs
"inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "IpStart" : 1,
                    "IpEnd" : -1
                },
                "indexName" : "IpStart_IpEnd",
                "isMultiKey" : false

@AlexBlex is possible to create a index and try to simulate a between function? I need one single document where the number provide should be inside the range of IpStart and IpEnd. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JoseSolano what do you mean by "simulate the between"? You can query for documents where values are within boundaries. What sql you are trying to translate to mongo query?

Comment: @AlexBlex, I was trying to translate this SQL: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ip_range_location] WHERE ipaddress BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end to mongo, so i did this: db.IpRangeLocations.find({"IpStart":{$lt:1209192009}, "IpEnd":{$gt:1209192009}}) but the performance is not the best, I think that the index that I am using in Mongo is not the correct. Is there another way to accomplish this? could you please provide an  example?

Comment: @JoseSolano the main reason why this is so is because in a compound index, the fields should be related to each other. In this case, I don't see an obvious relation between `IpStart` and `IpEnd`, and would think that they diverge. If the fields diverge, indexes would not help you, and could be detrimental since MongoDB is now doing the unnecessary work of scanning a divergent index. As Alex Blex was saying, the query is not a "between" query. Do the query in SQL and MongoDB return the same results? Could you post your SQL tables & queries?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha, I have added SQL to the question. It's kind of "reverse" between. If I get it right, Jose is trying to find ranges that include the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to optimize MongoDB query with both $gt and $lte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057387/how-to-optimize-mongodb-query-with-both-gt-and-lte)

Comment: @AlexBlex is right, but I want to implement an index which will help me to accomplish this in no more that 100ms, I am going to try implementing 2d indexes, thank you all for the help and the comments, I will let you know my results